# no output to console when using <chrono>

Tags: c++, c++11, cout, c++-chrono

I'm using QTCreator 2.8.1. with MinGW 4.8.1. compiler. I noticed that i cant output anything to console when working with std::chrono::high_resolution_clock. That means that this code doesn't print anything to console:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

int main(){

    cout << "HELLO" << endl;

    auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();


    return 0;
}
```

when i comment the line "auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();" out, "HELLO" gets printed to the console. I made also a video of this behaviour so you can see for yourself. Is the error on my side here? [enter link description here](http://www.screenr.com/B1nH)

Comment: Did you try "pausing" the program, e.g. by requesting input (`cin.ignore();`), before calling `high_resolution_clock::now()`?

Comment: no, the code was just as stated. I didn't use cin.ignore() or other statements.

Comment: @Grundkurs Then maybe try to do that.

Comment: @Grundkurs The problem is with your environment, not your code. [Works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0c0bbc55c9c82eae)